# Show that $\sigma (A) \subseteq [a,b]$ and contains the points $a$ and $b.$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

> Let $A$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ and let $$a = \inf_{\|x\|=1} \left \langle Ax,x \right \rangle,\ \ b = \sup\limits_{\|x\| = 1} \left \langle Ax, x \right \rangle$$
>
> Then the spectrum $\sigma (A)$ of $A$ is contained in the interval $[a,b]$ and contains the points $a$ and $b.$

I have tried to prove it but failed to proceed further. Could anybody give me some suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $\mathcal{H}$ of finite dimension ?

Comment: @Tuvasbien not necessarily.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: @Disintegrating By Parts I have almost finished the proof last night except for a single part to show that $a \in \sigma (A).$ WLOG we may assume that $a=0$ for otherwise we may work with the operator $A−aI$ which is still self-adjoint. With that assumption $A$ becomes a positive self-adjoint operator. But now I have to show that $0$ is an approximate eigenvalue of $A.$ In other words we need to show that $A$ is not bounded below. But I find it difficult to show this. Would you please help me in this regard? Thanks!

Comment: @Distegrating By Parts do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very clever, elementary trick that you might not know about, which uses the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for an inner product or pseudo inner product such as
$$
                [x,y] =  \langle (A-aI)x,y\rangle.
$$
This form has all of the properties of an inner product, except possibly strict positivity. Cauchy-Schwarz still holds:
$$
             |[x,y]|^2 \le [x,x][y,y].
$$
Now, set $y=(A-aI)x$:
\begin{align}
       \|(A-aI)x\|^4 &\le \langle(A-aI)x,x\rangle\langle (A-aI)^2x,(A-aI)x\rangle \\
            \|(A-aI)x\|^4 &\le \langle(A-aI)x,x\rangle \|(A-aI)^2x\|\|(A-aI)x\| \\
              &\le \langle (A-aI)x,x\rangle\|(A-aI)\|\|(A-aI)x\|^2\\
             \|(A-aI)x\|^2&\le\|(A-aI)\|\langle(A-aI)x,x\rangle.
\end{align}
Now you see that, if $\{ x_n \}$ is a sequence of unit vectors chosen so that $\langle(A-aI)x_n,x_n\rangle\rightarrow 0$, then $(A-aI)x_n\rightarrow 0$. That's enough to guarantee that $a\in\sigma(A)$. Similarly, $b\in\sigma(A)$.

Without using this Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for general inner products or pseudo inner products, I don't know how you would come up with this. It's a trick worth knowing because it proves that, for a bounded self-adjoint $A$, both $\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle$ and $\inf_{\|x\|=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle$ are in the spectrum of $A$. And it proves that the spectrum is non-empty as well. If $A$ is compact, you get eigenvectors with eigenvalues equal to the $\sup$ and $\inf$, and that ends up giving you a full spectral decomposition for the compact $A$ in terms of eigenvectors.

Comment: I haven't read about spectrum of a compact operator yet. Do you mean for a compact self-adjoint operator $a$ and $b$ are in the point spectrum? BTW I am able to prove at last what I wished to prove. But I am considering the underlying Hilbert space to be complex. I don't know how to prove the fact for real Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @Fanatics : For compact operators, $a$ and $b$ are eigenvalues. The argument using Cauchy-Schwarz works for real or complex spaces.